# El provider no se esta ejecutando

Tags: flutter

Hola a toddos estoy trabajando con Flutter y me gustaria saber lo siguiente. tengo esta clase en la que adjunto el codigo.

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

  class MovieProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  menuprovider() {
  print("provider inicializado");
  getondisplaymovies();
  } 

  getondisplaymovies() {
  print("fin");
  notifyListeners();
  }
  }
```

luego de ello en mi archivo main de mi app esto:
void main() => runApp(const AppState());

```
 class AppState extends StatelessWidget {
 const AppState({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => MovieProvider(),
      lazy: false,
    )
  ],
  child: const MyApp(),
  );
 }
 }
```

cuando instancio la clase antes mencionada a traves del 'create' no se ejecutan ninguna de las dos funciones que tienen el print. creo deberia poder ver en pantalla del terminal en visual studio code lo que imprimen ambas funciones pero no sucede. podrian porfa expicarme si estoy haciendo algo mal? soy nuevo en esto de la programación

Comment: En donde llamas a menuProvider y getondisplaymovies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una vez declaras las funciones, debes llamarlas para que se ejecuten...

```
 class AppState extends StatelessWidget {
 const AppState({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => MovieProvider()..menuProvider()..getOnDisplayMovies(),
      lazy: false,
    )
  ],
  child: const MyApp(),
  );
 }
 }
```

Sin embargo, parece que estás dando un salto muy grande. Antes de saltar un FrameWork como puede ser Flutter, primero debes entender bien las bases del lenguaje(Dart) y sobre todo de la programación. Un saludo.

Comment: definitivamente repasare las bases de dart y programacion antes de continuar. Un millon de Graciaaas!!!